# new page in asp.net mvc website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

I am assigned to add a new page to existing website which is probably mvc1

I copied contents of a page xyz.aspx and made new file xyz1.aspx in same folder

mybasepath/home/xyz works fine but mybasepath/home/xyz1 does not

I know asp.net mvc3,4. If there is a controller (cs file) having a method Index returning string.empty

then we get a vaild url for that controller

But this has no controller folder. All pages exist as root/views/home/xyz.aspx. None of both xyz and xyz1 contain and code behind c# file.

What else i might have to do to make mybasepath/home/xyz1 working or even mybasepath/home/xyz_text.txt working

None of the files contain any specific page names still i would share as per SO policy :)

**Global.asax**

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MvcASPCart.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

**Web.Config at root**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

  <appSettings>

  </appSettings>
  <system.web>

    <urlMappings enabled="true">

      <add url="~/Reviews" mappedUrl="~/Home/Reviews" />

    </urlMappings>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="120"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>

    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>


    <pages validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Linq" />
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.web.extensions />

  <system.webServer>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
    </handlers>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>

        <clear />
        <rule name="Redirect to wwww" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^xyz\.com.au$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="xyz.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>


      </rules>
    </rewrite>

  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="linyongtang1000@163.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="smtp.163.com" port="25" userName="linyongtang1000" password="2232857" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>


</configuration>
```

Comment: What does the routing configuration code look like?

Comment: Ok I share my web.config

Comment: return View("~/home/xyz1.aspx");

Comment: Check the Global.asax may be they harcoded each page as a route?